# Dropdownlist does not update after adding update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, updatepanel

I have multiple dropdownlist box all querying the same column, same table and from the same database. For example under memberID column i have the following IDs.

1. 12345
2. 23456
3. 34567

And i have 3 different dropdownlist box as shown below

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="memberID3" runat="server" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlpid3_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="memberID1" runat="server" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlpid1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="memberID2" runat="server" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlpid2_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

I added update panel between the dropdownlist so as to allow my dropdownlist to refresh upon any updates/selections.

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
  </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

For instance, when memberID1 selected 12345, the other 2 dropdownlist (memberID2 and 3) will not display the ID 12345. Vice versa, when memberID1 select the default value of the dropdownlist, the ID reappears in the other 2 dropdownlistbox. I have added a default value for all of the DDL.

```
 memeberID(number).Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Please select a Member ID", ""));
 memeberID(number).SelectedIndex = 0;
```

If i have not mistaken the property of update panel, isn't that able to make this function work?

here is the binding code as requested.

```
protected void ddllocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (var connAdd = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI"))
        {
            connAdd.Open();

            var sql = "Select policeid from PoliceAccount where status ='available' and handle ='offcase' and postedto='" + ddllocation.SelectedValue + "'";
            using (var cmdAdd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connAdd))
            {
                DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                cmdAdd.Fill(ds2);

                memberID1.Items.Clear();
                memberID1.DataSource = ds2;
                memberID1.DataTextField = "memberID";
                memberID1.DataValueField = "memberID";
                memberID1.DataBind();
                memberID1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select a Member ID", ""));
                memberID1.SelectedIndex = 0;

                memberID2.Items.Clear();
                memberID2.DataSource = ds2;
                memberID2.DataTextField = "memberID";
                memberID2.DataValueField = "memberID";
                memberID2.DataBind();
                memberID2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select a Member ID", ""));
                memberID2.SelectedIndex = 0;

                memberID3.Items.Clear();
                memberID3.DataSource = ds2;
                memberID3.DataTextField = "memberID";
                memberID3.DataValueField = "memberID";
                memberID3.DataBind();
                memberID3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select a Member ID", ""));
                memberID3.SelectedIndex = 0;



            }
```

***UPDATE***

For now i'm able to allow my other ddl to re-bind and cache the selected value in the other dropdownlist when the default value is selected. However, when i select other ID, the ID are being removed and it wont re-bind the other ddl.

```
protected void FillddlLocations()
    {
        FillDropdown(ddlpid1);
        FillDropdown(ddlpid2);
        FillDropdown(ddlpid3);
        FillDropdown(ddlpid4);
        FillDropdown(ddlpid5);
        ddlpid1.Visible = false;
        ddlpid2.Visible = false;
        ddlpid3.Visible = false;
        ddlpid4.Visible = false;
        ddlpid5.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void FillDropdown(DropDownList ddl)
    {

        using (var connAdd = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI"))
        {
            connAdd.Open();

            var sql = "Select policeid from PoliceAccount where status ='available' and handle ='offcase' and postedto='" + ddllocation.SelectedValue + "'";
            using (var cmdAdd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connAdd))
            {
                DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                cmdAdd.Fill(ds2);

                ddl.Items.Clear();
                ddl.DataSource = ds2;
                ddl.DataBind();
                ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Police ID", ""));
                ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;

            }

        }
    }

    protected void ddlpid1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ddlpid1.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {

            Session["pid1"] = ddlpid1.SelectedValue;

            ListItem removeItem2 = ddlpid2.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid1.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid2.Items.Remove(removeItem2);
            ListItem removeItem3 = ddlpid3.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid1.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid3.Items.Remove(removeItem3);
            ListItem removeItem4 = ddlpid4.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid1.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid4.Items.Remove(removeItem4);
            ListItem removeItem5 = ddlpid5.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid1.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid5.Items.Remove(removeItem5);


        }

        else

        if (ddlpid1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("Police ID"))
        {
            FillDropdown(ddlpid1);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid2);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid3);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid4);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid5);


            ddlpid2.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid2"];
            ddlpid2_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            ddlpid3.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid3"];
            ddlpid3_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            ddlpid4.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid4"];
            ddlpid4_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            ddlpid5.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid5"];
            ddlpid5_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }





    }

    protected void ddlpid2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ddlpid2.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {

            Session["pid2"] = ddlpid2.SelectedValue;
            ListItem removeItem1 = ddlpid1.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid2.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid1.Items.Remove(removeItem1);
            ListItem removeItem3 = ddlpid3.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid2.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid3.Items.Remove(removeItem3);
            ListItem removeItem4 = ddlpid4.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid2.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid4.Items.Remove(removeItem4);
            ListItem removeItem5 = ddlpid5.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid2.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid5.Items.Remove(removeItem5);


        }
        else if (ddlpid2.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("Police ID"))
        {
            FillDropdown(ddlpid1);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid2);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid3);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid4);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid5);

            ddlpid1.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid1"];
            ddlpid1_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            ddlpid3.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid3"];
            ddlpid3_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            ddlpid4.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid4"];
            ddlpid4_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            ddlpid5.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid5"];
            ddlpid5_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }


    }   

    protected void ddlpid3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        if (ddlpid3.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {

            Session["pid3"] = ddlpid3.SelectedValue;
            ListItem removeItem1 = ddlpid1.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid3.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid1.Items.Remove(removeItem1);
            ListItem removeItem2 = ddlpid2.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid3.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid2.Items.Remove(removeItem2);
            ListItem removeItem4 = ddlpid4.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid3.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid4.Items.Remove(removeItem4);
            ListItem removeItem5 = ddlpid5.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid3.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid5.Items.Remove(removeItem5);


        }   
    else if (ddlpid3.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("Police ID"))
        {
            FillDropdown(ddlpid1);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid2);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid3);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid4);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid5);

            ddlpid1.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid1"];
            ddlpid1_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            ddlpid2.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid2"];
            ddlpid2_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            ddlpid4.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid4"];
            ddlpid4_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            ddlpid5.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid5"];
            ddlpid5_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }


    }

    protected void ddlpid4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (ddlpid4.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            Session["pid4"] = ddlpid4.SelectedValue;

            ListItem removeItem1 = ddlpid1.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid4.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid1.Items.Remove(removeItem1);
            ListItem removeItem2 = ddlpid2.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid4.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid2.Items.Remove(removeItem2);
            ListItem removeItem3 = ddlpid3.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid4.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid3.Items.Remove(removeItem3);
            ListItem removeItem5 = ddlpid5.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid4.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid5.Items.Remove(removeItem5);


        }

        else if (ddlpid4.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("Police ID"))
        {


            FillDropdown(ddlpid1);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid2);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid3);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid4);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid5);

            ddlpid1.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid1"];
            ddlpid1_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            ddlpid2.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid2"];
            ddlpid2_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            ddlpid3.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid3"];
            ddlpid3_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            ddlpid5.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid5"];
            ddlpid5_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }


    }       

    protected void ddlpid5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           

        if (ddlpid5.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {

            Session["pid5"] = ddlpid5.SelectedValue;
            ListItem removeItem1 = ddlpid1.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid5.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid1.Items.Remove(removeItem1);
            ListItem removeItem2 = ddlpid2.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid5.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid2.Items.Remove(removeItem2);
            ListItem removeItem3 = ddlpid3.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid5.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid3.Items.Remove(removeItem3);
            ListItem removeItem4 = ddlpid4.Items.FindByValue(ddlpid5.SelectedValue);
            ddlpid4.Items.Remove(removeItem4);

        }

    else if (ddlpid5.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("Police ID"))
        {
            FillDropdown(ddlpid1);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid2);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid3);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid4);
            FillDropdown(ddlpid5);

            ddlpid1.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid1"];
            ddlpid1_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            ddlpid2.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid2"];
            ddlpid2_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            ddlpid3.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid3"];
            ddlpid3_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            ddlpid4.SelectedValue = (String)Session["pid4"];
            ddlpid4_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

    }
```

Comment: So you don't want the drop down lists to update in parallel or you do?

Comment: what do you mean by update in parallel?

Comment: Do you want all three drop down lists to have the same value when one of them updates or should they not stay in sync with each other?

Comment: Does it work differently with and without the update panel?  If so, please describe the differences.

Comment: Yes. I have all 3 dropdownlist to query and display the 3 member ID. For example, When any of dropdownlist select the ID `12345`, this ID will not appear on the other 2 dropdownlist. However, when the user re-select and chose the default value `Please select a Member ID`, the ID `12345` will re-appear on the other 2 dropdownlist.

Comment: @Greg To be honest, it seems like there isn't any difference, therefore i tried using update panel to make the dropdownlist update upon selection but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't think drop downs are supposed to do this by default.  The important parts are probably in the code you haven't posted - the binding code and the selected index changed code.  This question may help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038675/asp-net-dropdownlist-in-sync

Comment: If i have not mistaken, the question you gave have a different objective from mine. He's attempting to bring over the selected value from one dropdownlist to the other dropdownlist. However, i'm trying to prevent the same value from appearing when one dropdownlist has already selected it. Regards.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer, but try setting the `DataSource` to `ds.Copy()` instead of `ds`;

Comment: I would recommend direct ajaxcall with jQuery plugin

Comment: @Greg doesnt work either.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan - In this case, I think I'll need to see a full working demo to help debug it.

Comment: You mean you need my entire code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would set the **AutoPostBack** property for dropdowns to true in my markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="memberID1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlpid1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="memberID2" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlpid2_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="memberID3" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlpid3_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Update: We can store selected values in view state and retrieve after repopulating the dropdownlists like below:

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    bool bFlag = true;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            FillddlLocations();
        }
    }

    //Properties to store selected value in ViewState

    protected string MemberID1Selection
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["MemberID1Selection"] != null)
                return ViewState["MemberID1Selection"].ToString();
            return "";
        }
        set { ViewState["MemberID1Selection"] = value; }
    }

    protected string MemberID2Selection
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["MemberID2Selection"] != null)
                return ViewState["MemberID2Selection"].ToString();
            return "";
        }
        set { ViewState["MemberID2Selection"] = value; }
    }

    protected string MemberID3Selection
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["MemberID3Selection"] != null)
                return ViewState["MemberID3Selection"].ToString();
            return "";
        }
        set { ViewState["MemberID3Selection"] = value; }
    }


    protected void FillddlLocations()
    {
        FillDropdown(memberID1);
        FillDropdown(memberID2);
        FillDropdown(memberID3);
        memberID1.Visible = true;
        memberID2.Visible = true;
        memberID3.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void FillDropdown(DropDownList ddl)
    {

        using (var connAdd = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI"))
        {
            connAdd.Open();

            var sql = "Select policeid from PoliceAccount where status ='available' and handle ='offcase' and postedto='" + ddllocation.SelectedValue + "'";
            using (var cmdAdd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connAdd))
            {
                DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                cmdAdd.Fill(ds2);


                ddl.Items.Clear();
                ddl.DataSource = ds2;
                ddl.DataTextField = "memberID";
                ddl.DataValueField = "memberID";
                ddl.DataBind();
                ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select a Member ID", ""));
                ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;

            }

        }
    }

    protected void IndexChanged(DropDownList ddlChanged, DropDownList ddlToFilter1, DropDownList ddlToFilter2)
    {
        string removeValue1 = ddlChanged == memberID1 ? MemberID1Selection : (ddlChanged == memberID2 ? MemberID2Selection : MemberID3Selection);
        string selValue2 = ddlChanged == memberID1 ? MemberID2Selection : (ddlChanged == memberID2 ? MemberID1Selection : MemberID1Selection);
        string selValue3 = ddlChanged == memberID1 ? MemberID3Selection : (ddlChanged == memberID2 ? MemberID3Selection : MemberID2Selection);

        bFlag = false;//Prevent fireing the code again while changing the index
        if (removeValue1 != "")
        {
            ListItem item1 = ddlToFilter1.Items.FindByValue(removeValue1);
            ddlToFilter1.Items.Remove(item1);
            ListItem item2 = ddlToFilter2.Items.FindByValue(removeValue1);
            ddlToFilter2.Items.Remove(item2);            
        }

        if (selValue3 != "")
        {
            ListItem item3 = ddlToFilter1.Items.FindByValue(selValue3);
            ddlToFilter1.Items.Remove(item3);
        }
        if (selValue2 != "")
        {
            ListItem item4 = ddlToFilter2.Items.FindByValue(selValue2);
            ddlToFilter2.Items.Remove(item4);
        }

        bFlag = false;
        ddlToFilter1.SelectedIndex = ddlToFilter1.Items.IndexOf(ddlToFilter1.Items.FindByValue(selValue2));
        ddlToFilter2.SelectedIndex = ddlToFilter2.Items.IndexOf(ddlToFilter2.Items.FindByValue(selValue3));
    }

    protected void ddlpid1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MemberID1Selection = memberID1.SelectedValue;
        if (bFlag)
        {
            FillDropdown(memberID2);
            FillDropdown(memberID3);
            IndexChanged(memberID1, memberID2, memberID3);
        }
    }

    protected void ddlpid2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MemberID2Selection = memberID2.SelectedValue;
        if (bFlag)
        {
            FillDropdown(memberID1);
            FillDropdown(memberID3);
            IndexChanged(memberID2, memberID1, memberID3);
        }
    }
    protected void ddlpid3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MemberID3Selection = memberID3.SelectedValue;
        if (bFlag)
        {
            FillDropdown(memberID1);
            FillDropdown(memberID2);
            IndexChanged(memberID3, memberID1, memberID2);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested the code and it is working for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: I have changed method name for memberID1 selectedindexchanged. Put a breakpoint and see if it is firing at all.

Comment: Okay, I got it! You should set 'AutoPostBack="true"' for the dropdownlists. Please check the code again.

Comment: Wait. I'm getting my data from my database. So i cannot try your method as you hard-coded the value in instead.

Comment: I have removed dummy data so that it should work with your db now.

Comment: Jeez. sorry. I misread the code but it's finally working. Thank you.

Comment: However i realized one problem. what should i put my `filldropdown` in `ddl1` and `dd2` as? I tried inputting `FillDropdown(memberID1);
    FillDropdown(memberID3);` into `ddl2` it re-fill with my default value whenever i make a selection. Is it possible for me to not let it refill back to its default value? I tried removing them and not putting it, however when i select a value, and deselect and tries to select it again, it is no longer there.

Comment: You have to save selectedvalue for each dropdown in ViewState. After populating dropdowns each time you have to set selectedindex from ViewState. Also, you have to prevent running the code for selectedindex_changed event. You can use a flag to indicate if it is changed by code or by the user clik.

Comment: do you mind if you add some reference / sample codes on how to deal with it. sorry for the trouble. regards.

Comment: Actually i thought of an idea is to use session to cache but which didnt really work. Is there any other method to prevent the rebinding from refreshing and caching the selected data?

Comment: @Teo Chuen Wei Bryan I will update the code... give me couple of hours

Comment: Take ur time. Actually i used session to prevent the selected value from disappearing while re-binding when i select the default value. However, i'm still unable to let it rebind and cache the  value while `SelectedIndex > 0`. I have updated my codes in the question

Comment: @Teo Chuen Wei Bryan - We can use Session, but I prefer ViewState to store selected value. Please see updated code, I hope it will help .

Comment: wow. it works but may i ask how do i do it if i have 5 dropdownlist? I tried 5 ddl for 2 hours and still didnt managed to get it out. I'm trying to see the difference between 3 or 5 and do any necessary changes. This problem has been hounding me for very long and i'm very grateful for your help and effort to render some assistance to me.

Comment: @Teo Chuen Wei Bryan - I can email you if you want to - add email to your profile. Probably we should not continue expanding this post.