# Prevent duplicate data from appear in another dropdownlist when it is selected by another dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have 3 dropdownlists (DDL), all being bind to this column named policeID.

The policeID column have 3 data values known as:

1. 123456
2. 234567
3. 345678

I'm trying to prevent the data from appearing in another ddl when it has already been selected in one ddl.

For example, I have 3 DDL, they are

1. DDL1
2. DDL2
3. DDL3

If DDL1 were to select 123456, this value 123456 will not appear in the other 2 DDL.

However when, the user de-select 123456 and chose the default value, this value 123456 will be able to see in all 3 DDL.

I have asked a question similiar at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984278/dropdownlist-does-not-update-after-adding-update-panel)

I have used update panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

but it doesn't work. Is there any other method to prevent repetitive data from appearing?

Regards.

This is how i bind my DDL to the SQL.

```
protected void ddllocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (var connAdd = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI"))
        {
            connAdd.Open();

            var sql = "Select policeid from PoliceAccount where status ='available' and handle ='offcase' and postedto='" + ddllocation.SelectedValue + "'";
            using (var cmdAdd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connAdd))
            {
                DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                cmdAdd.Fill(ds2);

                ddlpid1.Items.Clear();
                ddlpid1.DataSource = ds2;
                ddlpid1.DataTextField = "policeid";
                ddlpid1.DataValueField = "policeid";
                ddlpid1.DataBind();
                ddlpid1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Police ID", ""));
                ddlpid1.SelectedIndex = 0;

                ddlpid2.Items.Clear();
                ddlpid2.DataSource = ds2;
                ddlpid2.DataTextField = "policeid";
                ddlpid2.DataValueField = "policeid";
                ddlpid2.DataBind();
                ddlpid2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Police ID", ""));
                ddlpid2.SelectedIndex = 0;

                ddlpid3.Items.Clear();
                ddlpid3.DataSource = ds2;
                ddlpid3.DataTextField = "policeid";
                ddlpid3.DataValueField = "policeid";
                ddlpid3.DataBind();
                ddlpid3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Police ID", ""));
                ddlpid3.SelectedIndex = 0;

                ddlpid4.Items.Clear();
                ddlpid4.DataSource = ds2;
                ddlpid4.DataTextField = "policeid";
                ddlpid4.DataValueField = "policeid";
                ddlpid4.DataBind();
                ddlpid4.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Police ID", ""));
                ddlpid4.SelectedIndex = 0;

                ddlpid5.Items.Clear();
                ddlpid5.DataSource = ds2;
                ddlpid5.DataTextField = "policeid";
                ddlpid5.DataValueField = "policeid";
                ddlpid5.DataBind();
                ddlpid5.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Police ID", ""));
                ddlpid5.SelectedIndex = 0;


            }
```

Comment: You can use the OnSelectedIndexchange event of the drop down, When this event triggers just get the list of items in the DropDown and bind only those values to the second drop down that you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cache to achieve this.Like this

```
    protected void bindDdls()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            ddlpid1.Items.Clear();
            ddlpid2.Items.Clear();
            using (var connAdd = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI"))
    {
        connAdd.Open();

        var sql = "Select policeid from PoliceAccount where status ='available' and handle ='offcase' and postedto='" + ddllocation.SelectedValue + "'";
        using (var cmdAdd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connAdd))
        {
            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
            cmdAdd.Fill(ds2);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ddlpid1.DataSource = dt;
                ddlpid1.DataTextField = dt.Columns["policeid"].ToString();
                ddlpid1.DataValueField = dt.Columns["policeid"].ToString();
                ddlpid1.DataBind();
                ddlpid1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "Select"));
            }
            else
            {
                ddlpid1.Items.Clear();
                ddlpid1.DataSource = null;
                ddlpid1.DataBind();
                ddlpid1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "Select"));
            }

            if (Cache["PoliceData"] == null)
            {
                Cache.Insert("PoliceData", dt);
            }
            else
            {
                Cache.Remove("PoliceData");
                Cache.Insert("PoliceData", dt);
            }

            connAdd.Close();
            }
          }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connAdd.State == connAdd.Open)
                connAdd.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void ddlpid1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlpid1.SelectedValue != "Select")
        {
            bindSecondDropdown();
        }
    }

    protected void bindSecondDropdown()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtFiltered = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            ddlpid2.Items.Clear();
            if (Cache["PoliceData"] != null)
            {
                dt = (DataTable)Cache["PoliceData"];
                if (ddlpid1.SelectedValue != "Select" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlpid1.SelectedValue))
                    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[policeID] <> " + ddlpid1.SelectedValue;
                else
                    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[policeID] <> " + 0;
                dtFiltered = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
            }

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ddlpid2.DataSource = dtFiltered;
                ddlpid2.DataTextField = dtFiltered.Columns["policeid"].ToString();
                ddlpid2.DataValueField = dtFiltered.Columns["policeid"].ToString();
                ddlpid2.DataBind();
                ddlpid2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "Select"));
            }
            else
            {
                ddlpid2.Items.Clear();
                ddlpid2.DataSource = null;
                ddlpid2.DataBind();
                ddlpid2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "Select"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex;
        }
    }
```

Use same Approach for the third dropdown.

Comment: i have editted the question by adding how i bind my DDL with the SQL. does it changes the code you gave?

Comment: now you can see edited code. You just need to call bindDdls() function based on your requirement.

Comment: I still dont quite understand the `protected void bindDdls()`. What aobut my `ddllocation`? I'm getting confused here.

Comment: Well, the purpose of bindDdls() function is to bind your first dropdown. once first dropdown is selected that time your second dropdown will bind and this dropdown2 will not contain the dropdown1 selectedItem. this is what you wanted.

Comment: hmm. but how do i put it in together within my dlllocation?

Comment: break your functions into 3 parts. 1)GetdatafromDatabase() in this function store dataTable to Cache. 2)BindFirstDropDown() in this function provide Cache["PoliceData"] as datasource to ddl1 3)BindSecondDropdown in this function use "dt.DefaultView.RowFilter" as datasource to ddl2. Now call GetdatafromDatabase() in ddllocation_SelectedIndexChanged event. The main thing u need to do is in defaultview u have to put ur logic so that the selectedItem would not reflect any of other dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rebind the DDL2 and DDL3 on SelectedIndexChanged event.

Here is the pseudo-code for rebinding on SelectedIndexChanged

```
Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for each item in datasource
{
list.Add(item.key, item.value);
}

if (ddl1.SelectedValue != defaultValue){

   var itemToRemove = list.First(kvp => kvp.Value == ddl1.SelectedValue);

   dic.Remove(itemToRemove .Key);
}

ddl2.DataSource = list;
ddl2.DataTextField = "Value";
ddl2.DataValueField = "Key";
ddl2.DataBind();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i have editted the question by adding how i bind my DDL with the SQL. does it changes the code you gave?

Comment: I see you are not removing the selected entries from the datasource that is binded.

CAn you do  ds2.Tables